# Баг в счётчике влияния в профиле

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, страница-учётной-записи

**Дано:**

1. Вопрос со 100К просмотрами и 2 ответами, заданный 3 года назад
2. Пользователь с влиянием 1К

Наш пользователь отвечает на этот вопрос и получает 2 голоса за.

**Результат:**

Пользователь с влиянием 101К

**Пример:**

- Вопрос: [Как сменить прокси сервер через cmd?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/101366/181472), 105к просмотров.
- Пользователь [dsnk](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/188827/dsnk): 107k людей затронул.

  ---

<sup>И не говорите мне, что это фича. 1К и близко с 101К не стояло. Это не примерное число.</sup>

Comment: Что в итоге, вас устраивает объяснение или настаиваете на том, что это баг? Подозреваю, что дорабатывать алгоритм в ближайшее время не будут, там и так список багов огромен (по словам Nicolas).

Comment: @NickVolynkin, на минутку пошёл ступор. Смотрю на ромб и думаю "Почему Николас говорит о себе в третьем лице?". Но потом решил прочитать имя до конца. :) 
Это однозначно баг. То, что его не будут исправлять - не означает, что мы должны сидеть и молчать, ведь так? )

Comment: Хе-хе ) Ну, это же довольно незначительный баг. Привилегий на сайте не дает, не выставляет пользователя хуже, чем есть (наоборот, намного лучше). Можно запостить на общую мету, но тогда нужна железная аргументация, почему этот баг нужно править.

Comment: Я даже не знаю, что и ответить. У меня нет опыта Meta SE. И одно то, что это Баг - аргумент, чтобы исправить (в моём представлении). На днях попробую там опубликоваться.

Comment: баг, но приоритет у него будет невысокий.

Answer (score 4):

При появлении этой статистики на странице учетной записи на Meta SE был опубликован анонсирующий пост: [We're working on a new stat to help convey the reach of your posts here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244534/296059). Вот что там пишут:

> - It's okay that it can't separate views that came before your answer, so long as it's very unusual that an answer posted way after the question on a popular question will count.
> - It's okay if it can get weird occasionally, as long as those cases are fairly rare, or will tend to occur when the number won't change that much anyway

> - Это нормально, что счетчик не отделяет просмотры, которые произошли до публикации вашего ответа. Крайне редко случается, что ответ, данный на очень популярный вопрос спустя долгое время, соответствует критериям и добавляет просмотры к общему показателю.
> - Это нормально, что иногда счетчик будет вести себя странно, пока это случается действительно редко и общий показатель не меняется слишком сильно.

Все предположения относительно фичи основаны вот на чем: на en.SO на большинство популярных вопросов дано более десятка ответов. Крайне маловероятно, что данный через длительное время ответ будет принят или войдет в тройку лучших. (А вот просто набрать 5 рейтинга он может легко.) В случае ru.SO ответов на вопросах гораздо меньше ответов, так что у нас больше шансов набрать статистику. В общем, дыра в фиче определенно есть, ее можно легко эксплуатировать, давая на старые популярные вопросы с отличными ответами новые ответы, которые ещё лучше. Ерунда, каждый так может )